# VLC streaming testbench

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, rtsp

Has anyone tried streaming media with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) as server? I want to deploy [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) as streaming server, but my department didn't had a nice experience with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) streaming.

My question is has anyone tried [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) streaming over LAN with as many as 200 clients? What were the precautions to be taken before going for the actual showdown? What kind of transport stream is better for a smoother live streaming?

Are any test bench I can use to convince my superiors?

Answer (score 0):

While I was developing a DVR for a specific purpose I did many [h264 streaming tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8705842/1007502) mainly using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) as the server and VLC as a player. The goal was a bit different, as I just needed a way to preview four cameras ([v4l2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) devices) in realtime, so I ended up streaming h264 video directly over UDP, but in the research process I also used VLC as the server, so maybe it can serve as a starting point for your testbench.

Assuming you are using Linux as your server platform, the command line below uses VLC command line client (*cvlc*) to get raw video from a v4l2 device (a webcam or a video card input), encoding it in h264 and then advertise the stream for a RTSP client to get:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=2048}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://@:8554/video.sdp}'
```

If you also use VLC as the client, you can view the stream with this (*server* would be the server name or IP address):

```
vlc rtsp://server:8554/video.sdp
```

Since you need to stream the video to many clients, it would be better to use [multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast), so your server doesn't have to send out a new stream for each connected client. Supposing your multicast address is 239.255.1.1, you just need to specify it on the RTP section:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=2048}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://@:8554/video.sdp, dst=239.255.1.1}'
```

Since the *video.sdp* file is generated by VLC itself, you just connect the same way as before, but your client will get the stream from the multicast address instead:

```
vlc rtsp://server:8554/video.sdp
```

Comment: I have tested vlc streaming server with http transport. I was unable to reach 100 clients. It seems to stop steam after i reach 80 clients...I have also issued a bug ticket in http://trac.videolan.org

Comment: Did you try using multicast?

Comment: If you directed all the 100 users to your server, each one creating a duplicate stream, you probably just ran out of bandwidth. For this kind of application multicasting should be the way to go.

Comment: i was using gigabit ethernet..i have tried all combinations... bandwidth, CPU, memory...everything..but that's not it!!

Comment: Ok.. it's not about the machine. Depending on the video bitrate even a gigabit ethernet can't cope with a dozen duplicate streams. Did you specifically try using multicast? In this mode you only send **one** video stream out of your server and the router manages to replicate that only stream to all the clients who request it, so you'll never have a bottleneck on your server output. Your 100 or so clients were all on the same subnet?

Comment: i was continuously monitoring the network thruput.. It wasn't network bottleneck...This happened even when I was streaming an mp3 audio...Now, an mp3 streaming doesn't consume more bandwidth than 256kbps...Btw, i was unicasting streams, not multicasting...

Comment: anyways, have u tried to scale up the client number??

Comment: Well, where I work at I don't have workstations enough to scale up. But I did experiment with multicast and it does work, the bandwidth out of the server remains the same with 1, 2 or 3 clients, and with unicast it goes up with every new connection.

Comment: you don't need so many machine...try running a vlc client with vout=dummy, codec=dummy option, so that cpu is not consumed..and now you can run multiple instances of vlc client on a same machine..I used 20 machines to simulate 100 clients....vlc will take the stream but will discard it without showing it on screen